# TFS 2015 Conditions for variables

Tags: variables, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

till last year we had a build.csproj file with all our build-definitions for a solution. Now we made an update from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015.
Now I have to define the build-definitions on the new websurface of the TFS 2015. Its not a problem to define the variables, but how do I work with conditions?
In the build.cjproj file its like

```
<GUIDChanged Condition="'$(ChangeProductID)' == 'true' OR '$(ChangePrinterDriverIDs)' == 'true'">true</GUIDChanged>
```

How do I got this in the websurface of the TFS 2015?

Thanks a lot!
Chris

Comment: Are you still using the old XAML builds, or the new vNext builds?

Comment: I wanted to use the new vNext builds, it seems that it is not implementet now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vNext there is no this built in feature for now. There has been  a related uservoice and got a response with **started**, you could keep tracking this.

> [Allow build vNext/preview tasks to be conditionally enabled or
>   disabled](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8623600-allow-build-vnext-preview-tasks-to-be-conditionall)
>
> **Started** *Team Services Group (Product group, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  ·  August 23, 2016*
>
> We have begun to work on this feature and it will be available on both
>   team build and release management.

For now you could either still use this XAML build or using multiple Build definition in vNext to handle this situation.